# HTML table; How to format content within 2nd column to align all - except first element - to right and stretch 1st element to fill remaining width

Tags: html, css, formatting, element

want to display the following:

[image]

- where the "..." button in the first row (Web Project) is completely right-aligned to the red line (with a little padding to it)
- where the Input field in the 2nd row (Root Namespace) is filling up the space to the right until the red line (with a little padding to it)
- where the 2 buttons in the 3rd row (Connection String) are completely right-aligned to the red line (with a liddle padding to it).

I have tried the following but it does not do it correctly - and it only works with a certain width - If I increase or decrease the width, things are getting ugly:

decreasing the width:

[image]

My current HTML looks like this:

```
<div id = "ProjectSelector" width = 100%>
        <table width = "100%" style = "padding-bottom: 10px;">
          <tr>
            <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 140px;">Web Project (.csproj)</td>
            <td style="width: 99%;" ><input id = "webproj" style="width: 97%"/><button id="webproj_browse">...</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Root Namespace</td>
            <td style="width: 99%;"><input id = "rootnamespace" style="width: 99%"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Connection String</td>
            <td style="width: 99%;"><select id = "connectionstring" style = "width: 87%"></select><button id="newConnection">New Connection</button><button id="connstringDelete">Delete</button></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```

Question: How to format the table and the content of 2nd column to accomplish this properly?

Comment: Do you really have to use `<table>`, Michael?

Comment: I am open to other solutions - as long as it produces the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the title of your question describes a typical flex behavior. You may use inside your table a flex container :

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="ProjectSelector" width=1 00%>
  <table width="100%" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <tr>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap; width:0;">Web Project (.csproj)</td>
      <td>
        <div class="flex"><input id="webproj" class="flex-1" /><button id="webproj_browse">...</button></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Root Namespace</td>
      <td>
        <div class="flex"><input id="rootnamespace" class="flex-1" /></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Connection String</td>
      <td>
        <div class="flex">
          <select id="connectionstring" class="flex-1"></select><button id="newConnection">New Connection</button><button id="connstringDelete">Delete</button></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

It can also be build with grid or flex without a table.

For infos & demo  , an example mixing grid and flex, *i would probably not use this HTML structure H + P at first* :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#ProjectSelector {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
  ;
}

p {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="ProjectSelector">
  <h4>Web Project (.csproj)</h4>
  <!-- title that matches your structure or else can be plain text -->
  <p class="flex"><input id="webproj" class="flex-1" /><button id="webproj_browse">...</button></p>
  <h4>Root Namespace</h4>
  <p class="flex"><input id="rootnamespace" class="flex-1" /></p>
  <h4>Connection String</h4>
  <p class="flex">
    <select id="connectionstring" class="flex-1"></select><button id="newConnection">New Connection</button><button id="connstringDelete">Delete</button></p>
</div>
```